# Winget can't install packages - 0x80070032 : The request is not supported

Tags: winget

I attempting to install lazygit and I cannot seem to get it installed.

```
❯ winget install lazygit
Failed in attempting to update the source: winget
Found lazygit [JesseDuffield.lazygit] Version 0.40.0
This application is licensed to you by its owner.
Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages.
An unexpected error occurred while executing the command:
0x80070032 : The request is not supported.
```

I tried other packages like Mozilla developer edition and it worked.
I tried doing a winget reset source, I tried adjusting the permissions.

Comment: Which version of WinGet are you encountering this problem on? You may need to update to the latest version.

Comment: @DemitriusNelon How do I update?

Comment: Check for updates in the Microsoft Store, or directly install via https://aka.ms/getwinget.